# Minimum weight BFS graph span of undirected graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

This is probably a beginner question at best, but have been playing with graphs and have been implementing BFS searches on various exercises. I can't quite figure out how to actually keep track on the weight of the edges I have visited in order to create a minimum complete spanning of the graph. My graph is in the format:

```
{0: [(1, 1), (2, 1)], 1: [(0, 1), (2, 1)], 2: [(1, 1), (0, 1)]}
```

Where the first vertice is 0 with adjacent vertices of 1 and 2 with weights of 1 and 1 respectively. So in clearer terms the keys in the graph dictionary represent vertices, and each tuple in the key value represent a vertice, weight pair.

So what I have in my BFS function is:

```
def bfs(graph, start):
    """returns total weight needed to visit 
    each vertice in the graph with the minimum
    overall weight possible"""
    if [] in graph.values():
        return "Not Possible"
    weight = 0
    visited, queue = set(), [start]
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.pop(0)
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            for node in graph[vertex]:
                queue.append(node[0])
                weight += node[1]
    return weight
```

At the moment with my original graph this function would return `6` where it should be `2`. I think this is because it is iterating over each vertice and adding the adjacent weights, even though they have already been visited.
This also wouldn't actually choose the minimum weighted path, it only keep track of the weight of the path it has taken, whatever that may be. How can I address this?

A longer example:

```
{0: [(1, 5), (2, 7), (3, 12)], 1: [(0, 5), (2, 9), (4, 7)], 2: [(0, 7), (1, 9), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 3)], 3: [(0, 12), (2, 4), (5, 7)], 4: [(1, 7), (2, 4), (5, 2), (6, 5)], 5: [(2, 3), (3, 7), (4, 2), (6, 2)], 6: [(4, 5), (5, 2)]}
```

This produces a weight of `134` where the correct answer should be `23`
Is there some algorithm I am missing that can keep track of the weighted edges and choose the best path from this?
I am aware of Dijkstra’s Algorithm but as far as I am aware that is suitable for a path with a designated start and end, and not a complete graph span?

Answer (score 0):

Dijkastra's algorithm and bfs are useful in finding minimum path between two vertices.However if you want to find the minimum spanning tree please check out Kruskal's algorithm instead.

Here is the link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm

Pseudocode:

```
KRUSKAL(G):
1 A = ∅
2 foreach v ∈ G.V:
3    MAKE-SET(v)
4 foreach (u, v) in G.E ordered by weight(u, v), increasing:
5    if FIND-SET(u) ≠ FIND-SET(v):
6       A = A ∪ {(u, v)}
7       UNION(u, v)
8 return A
```

It is implemented using union-find(disjointed set) data structure.